# Static hosting on S3 can only be done by CNAME from subdomain?

Tags: hosting, dns, amazon-s3, scalability, cname

I read this:

"I can't use this until I can serve my root domain without redirection to "www". Can Amazon designate an IP address (or set of IP addresses) for S3 that I can point my root A record to?"

Is it still true that I need to have a domain host just as a proxy to S3 and setup CNAME to point a subdomain to S3 bucket? And there is no better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no better ways, only most costly ways.

You can set up an EC2 image with a proxy, and allow the proxy to access S3 on your behalf, while accessing the remainder of your web site somewhere else.  Since scalability is a concern of yours, you'll also want to use the automatic scaling tools for EC2 as access to your proxy grows.

Or, just re-architect your application to use the CNAME-based approach for all content located in S3.

Comment: for CNAME, should it be set to the end point :  www.domain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ OR just www.amazonaws.com, if the sub I'm using is www

Comment: I figured. the end point is what works. just needed DNS to refresh. the example here made me wonder for a bit with regards to the CNAME url: http://5thirtyone.com/tutorial/amazon-s3-cname-record-panics-transmit-and-wordpress/

Comment: That's a good tutorial site.  I learned some extra techniques reading through it just now.